# Jersey @PathParam : contains multiple parameters with no annotation

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

The following is my method signature which I am using in Jersey , when I debug/run the program I am getting error as :

> [[FATAL] Method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.xxxx.xxxxx.Xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext) on resource class com.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx contains multiple parameters with no annotation.

My code:

```
@PUT
@Path("/user/{user}/{role}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Produces("application/json")

public Response myFunction(@PathParam("user") String user,
    @PathParam("role") String role,
    String rawData,
    @Context ContainerRequestContext crc) {

}
```

What I am doing wrong here.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Edit: This answer helped me solve my error, but as Cássio Mazzochi Molin mentioned in the comment below: it wont help you (and the documentation is for the wrong version of Jersey..). A total miss on my part.

Please excuse my attempt to help you. I hope you already have solved your error :)

> Ahoy there!
>
> I'm really new to REST (so take my answer with a bucket of herb salt),
>   but I think I know where your error is coming from.
>
> You have to *bind* your parameter `rawData`.
>
> Example: `@PathParam("rawdata") String rawData` or
>   `@HeaderParam("rawdata") String rawData`
>
> Depending on where you want to extract the parameter from you have to
>   write a @annotation to the parameter.
>
> > You can extract the following types of parameters for use in your
> >     resource class:
> >
> > - Query
> > - URI
> > - Path
> > - Form
> > - Cookie
> > - Header
> > - Matrix
>
> Text above is taken from the link:
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html You should
>   take a look and read a little about it if you haven't done it already
>   :)

Comment: **1.** I don't think this part accurate: _You have to_ bind _your parameter `rawData`_. The method is annotated with `@PUT`, hence the `rawData` should be sent in the request payload and no `@___Param` annotation is required. **2.** Jersey 2.x (see the tag in the question) is part of Java EE 7 and the link you provided is from Java EE 6. The documentation is not wrong though.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me.I had the same problem (but with `@GET`) and this solved my problem. And I didn't know that there could be a difference between `@GET`and `@PUT`. Maybe I should know more about a subject before trying to solve others problems. Lesson learned :)

Comment: The difference is that `GET` request doesn't have (at least *shouldn't have*) a request payload. I understand the OP is receiving the `rawData` in the payload (body) of a `PUT` request.